# Force a form to stay on top

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I want a form to be shown modal every time it is opend. Since I can not change the way it is created and opend. I wondered if it is possible to make the form stay on top from within the forms class.

One opportunity is the `TopMost` property. This works in general, but if I display the form while the main thread is waiting for it to close, the form will stay on top even if I change the application(to a browser for example). So no matter where I am, the form is still displayed.

Another issue which I came across is that in some cases it is adopted by the parent form which then might block other windows or popup messages.

I was thinking about a hook to the `OnLostFocus` event to get it on top again, once the focus is lost, but I'm not sure if that is a good idea ...

Any helpful thoughts about it?

---

**Edit**

Due to the comments I will extend my description, Here is the real use-case

We are using the Devexpress's `SplashScreenManager` which is able to show a certain form as a `WaitForm`. Since the `WaitForm` is not intended to be shown modal([see on the Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q437986.aspx)), we are looking for a way to do so.

We can not change the way the form is shown, because this is done through the `SplashScreenManager`. The `WaitForm` is shown both from the main thread, as well as from certain backgroundworker.

So this is only about an own form of ourselfs, displaying it within our own application.

Comment: What if there was another application that employed the same logic?  Doesn't work.

Comment: @LarsTech I updated my question with more details.

Comment: You can make any non-modal form modal with just two changes.  First make it an *owned* window so it is always on top of another window.  The Show(owner) overload does that.  Secondly, prevent input into the other windows by setting their Enabled property to false.  Make sure to re-enable them before you close the 'dialog' window.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for you comment. I did not really understood your first part. I cannot influence the way the form is shown, it's called by the `SplashScreenManager`, so I can't call `Show(owner)` myself

Comment: You may find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) interesting

Comment: You already know from the DevXpress answer that SplashScreenManager is broken.  So don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did not want the TopMost property since it works on windows level and covers other windows too (for example the browser).
In the end I hooked up on the focus event of the window to make sure the window is always on top.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
TopLevel = true;
```

This will do exactly what you want; be topmost as long as the main form is shown and hide if the mainform is hidden by another window.

You can set the owner of your splash form to your main form explicitly without using .Show(owner).

```
splashForm.Owner=mainForm;
splashManager.Show(splashForm);
```